# Facebook SDK FBSession code not working with Swift

Tags: ios, facebook, xcode6

Trying to implement this Objective C code in Swift:

```
    // Whenever a person opens the app, check for a cached session
    if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {

    // If there's one, just open the session silently, without showing the user the login UI
      [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"]
                                 allowLoginUI:NO
                            completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                              // Handler for session state changes
                              // This method will be called EACH time the session state changes,
                              // also for intermediate states and NOT just when the session open
                              [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
                            }];
```

But getting error with FBSession.activeSession.state.value in this line:

```
if FBSession.activeSession.state.value == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded.value {
        FBSession.openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions(self.facebookReadPermissions, allowLoginUI: true, completionHandler: {(session, state, error) -> Void in
                self.sessionStateChanged(session, state: state, error: error)
            })
    }
```

Please help.

Comment: This is the error: '() -> FBSession!' does not have a member named 'state'and if I remove value from this line I get this error: 'FBSessionState' is not convertible to 'NSObject'

Comment: Hi @Cathal, Sorry to drop a comment here, but I am desperate and I wonder how did you manage to import FBSession in the first place in Swift? Where is FBSession located?

Answer (score 2):

Change your first if statement with this

```
    if(FBSession.activeSession().state == FBSessionState.CreatedTokenLoaded)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 if(fbsessionState.value != FBSessionStateOpen.value && fbsessionState.value != FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended.value)
    {

        let permission = ["email","public_profile", "user_friends" ];

        FBSession.openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions(permission, defaultAudience: FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends, allowLoginUI: true, completionHandler: self.handlerFB);

    }

func handlerFB(session:FBSession!, state:FBSessionState, error:NSError!)
{
    if let gotError = error
    {

    }
    else
    {

        self.fbSession = session;

        FBRequest.requestForMe()?.startWithCompletionHandler(self.requestfbComplete);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but my issue is that 'FBSessionState' does not have a member named 'value'- so this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score -1):

IN SWIFT

```
if FBSession.activeSession().state == FBSessionState.CreatedTokenLoaded {
    FBSession.openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions(["public_profile","email"], 
        allowLoginUI: true, 
        completionHandler:{(session, state, error) in
            self.sessionStateChanged(session, state: state, error: error)
        })
}
```

Answer (score -3):

FBSession is not member of AnyObject in swift. FBSession is not allow in swift